# Prove $A$ is either finite or countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A$ be a set and let $f:A \to \Bbb{N}$ be an injection. Prove $A$ is either finite or countable. 
How can one prove such a thing? Since this is so obvious it gets me in a place where I don't know what I can and cannot assume. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: In some cases this would be a definition of finite or countable.  In your context you are probably using some other definition.  What is that definition?

Comment: Every subset of $\mathbb N$ is finite or countable. The injectivity of $f$ ensures that $A$ is isomorphic to a such a set. Btw, quite often (maybe even always) finite sets are by definition countable.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is an injection, you know that the map $f\colon A\rightarrow f(A)\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is a bijection. This means that $A$ and $f(A)$ have the same cardinality. You are then left with the problem of considering the possible cardinalities of a subset $f(A)$ of $\mathbb{N}$. I hope this helps.